# exit status returns '0' even with command failure

Tags: bash, shell, perl

I want to redirect my command output (standard output and standard error) to test.log file with below code.

I am trying to check the exit status of my command by giving some invalid option `(-force)` to `ls`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#system("ls 2>&1 | tee logfile");
#system("ls > lllog ");'
my $cmd = &exec_cmd("cd reg_folder && ls -force 2>&1 | tee test.log");

sub exec_cmd{
   system(@_);
   my $result = $?;
   print "===result $result===\n";
   if(($result) != 0) {
     print "status $result\n";
     exit;
   }
   return $result;
}
```

Output:-

```
ls: invalid option -- 'e'
Try `ls --help' for more information.
===result 0===
```

After running system command , I am expecting the exit status should be non-zero and it has to enter **if** block. But it is showing exit status as `0` though the command failed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is because you're piping output into `tee test.log`. The exit status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command in the pipeline, and `tee` is exiting successfully.

The `pipefail` shell option (which is available in `bash` but *not* in
a legacy Bourne shell) modifies this behavior:

> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last
> command,  unless  the `pipefail`  option is enabled.  If `pipefail` is
> enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of the last
> (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero  if all
> commands  exit  successfully. (from the `bash(1)` man page)

So if you were to write...

```
my $cmd = &exec_cmd("set -o pipefail; cd reg_folder && ls -force 2>&1 | tee test.log");
```

...you'll get the exit code you expect.

---

Alternatively, you could handle more of the mechanics in Perl rather
than relying on the shell for i/o redirection, etc.

Comment: I am working with tcsh. It worked, Thanks!

Comment: @RAMA, Re "*I am working with tcsh.*", No you're not. `system` uses `/bin/sh`